# How to make my own while Loop just like Wordpress Loop?

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, while-loop

im new here and new in PHP too..

Just wondering how to make my own flexible loop just like in Wordpress...
Note im not talking about wordpress.. I want to implement it on myown PHP application...

let's look back in WP, there is a code something like this:

```
while (have_post() : thepost())// .. bla bla...

echo the_title();
echo the_content();

endwhile; // this is just an ilustration
```

Could you figure out how have_post() or the_post() interact with database, 
so that they can be loop..

thanks..

Answer (score 8):

WordPress uses global variables that these functions modify when iterating through the loop. e.g.:

```
var $posts = null;
var $post = null;
var $post_count = 0;
var $post_index = 0;

function have_post() {
    global $posts, $post_count, $post_index;

    $post_index = 0;

    // do a database call to retrieve the posts.
    $posts = mysql_query('select * from posts where ...');

    if ($posts) {
        $post_count = count($posts);
        return true;
    } else {
        $post_count = 0;
        return false;
    }
}

function thepost() {
    global $posts, $post, $post_count, $post_index;

    // make sure all the posts haven't already been looped through
    if ($post_index > $post_count) {
        return false;
    }

    // retrieve the post data for the current index
    $post = $posts[$post_index];

    // increment the index for the next time this method is called
    $post_index++;

    return $post;
}

function the_title() {
    global $post;
    return $post['title'];
}

function the_content() {
    global $post;
    return $post['content'];
}
```

I would definitely recommend using OOP style coding over what WordPress does, however.  This will keep variables definied within an instance of an object instead of being globally accessible.  e.g.:

```
class Post {
    function __construct($title, $content) {
        $this->title = $title;
        $this->content = $content;
    }

    function getTitle() {
        return $title;
    }

    function getContent() {
        return $content;
    }
}

class Posts {
    var $postCount = 0;
    var $posts = null;

    function __construct($conditions) {
        $rs = mysql_query('select * from posts where $conditions...');

        if ($rs) {
            $this->postCount = count($rs);
            $this->posts = array();

            foreach ($rs as $row) {
                $this->posts[] = new Post($row['title'], $row['content']);
            }
        }
    }

    function getPostCount() {
        return $this->postCount;
    }

    function getPost($index) {
        return $this->posts[$index];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You could implement the [Iterator](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.iterator.php) interface.

Comment: Replace “need to” with “could”.

Answer (score 1):

the idea is to use global scope variables, and then the functions will modify those variables:

```
// first define the global variables:
$post_index = 0;
$posts_count = 0;
$post = null;
$posts = null;
$connection = null;

$connection = new PDO('mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=YOUR_DB', 'YOUR_DB_USERNAME', 'YOUR_DB_USER_PASSWORD', array(PDO::ATTR_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC));

$query = $connection->query('SELECT * FROM posts');
$posts = $query->fetchAll();

$posts_count = count($posts); // or = $query->rowCount()

// now you create the functions that will deal with and change those variables

function have_posts()
{
    global $post_index, $posts_count, $posts, $post;
    // if posts found and if post_index < posts_count return true else return false
    if($posts && $post_index < $post_count)
        return true;

    else
        return false;
}

function the_post()
{
    global $post_count, $post_index, $posts, $post;

    if($post_index > $post_count)
        return false;
    // fetch the post of the current index
    $post = $posts[$post_index];

    // increment the $post_index so that the next call to this function grapes the next post
    $post_index++;
}

function get_ID()
{
    global $post;
    return $post['ID'];
}


function get_title()
{
    global $post;
    return $post['title'];
}
```

I hope that help.

Answer (score 0):

Go to this problem again :D

finally I got the solution,

@Matt Huggins, i have made some revision to your code, 
and now it's work...

```
$posts = $wpdb->get_results('SELECT * FROM my_table',OBJECT);
$post = null;
$post_count = 0;
$post_index = 0;

function have_post() {
    global $posts, $post_count, $post_index;

    if ($posts && ($post_index <= $post_count)){
        $post_count = count($posts);
        return true;
    }
    else {
        $post_count = 0;
        return false;
    }
}

function the_post() {
    global $posts, $post, $post_count, $post_index;

    // make sure all the posts haven't already been looped through
    if ($post_index > $post_count) {
        return false;
    }

    // retrieve the post data for the current index
    $post = $posts[$post_index+1];

    // increment the index for the next time this method is called
    $post_index++;
    return $post;

}

function the_title() {
    global $post;
    return $post->Title;
}

function the_content() {
    global $post;
    return $post->Content;
}

//and the output

if(have_post()) : while(have_post()) : the_post();
echo '<h2>'.the_title().'</h2>';
echo '<p>'.the_content().'</p>';
endwhile; endif;
```

Many thanks... :)